# Always get session nil using FBSDK 3.x in Swift

Tags: ios, swift

I'm a new swift developer. I'm trying to get the the photo albums from Facebook. When I request the permission the session always return nil. The code like this:

```
func login(){

    let activeSession = FBSession.activeSession();
    let fbsessionState = activeSession.state.hashValue;
    if(fbsessionState == FBSessionState.CreatedTokenLoaded.hashValue){
        let permission = ["user_friends","public_profile", "email","user_photos","user_likes","user_posts","publish_actions"];
        FBSession.openActiveSessionWithPublishPermissions(permission, defaultAudience: FBSessionDefaultAudience.Friends, allowLoginUI: true, completionHandler: self.fbHandler);    
    }
}


func fbHandler(session:FBSession!, state:FBSessionState, error:NSError!){
    if let gotError = error{
        print(gotError.description)
    }
    else{
        self.fbSession = session;
        if (fbSession?.isOpen != nil){
           FBRequest.requestForMe()?.startWithCompletionHandler(self.fbRequestCompletionHandler);
        }  
    }
}
```

So can someone help me to avoid from getting always nil of session.

Comment: FB released 4.x SDK. Please use it.

Comment: My problem was solved by using the last version of FBSDK. Thanks.